# Cannot figure out CORS in .net core 3.1 web api

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, cors

I've tried moving all my method calls around no less than 10,000 times. I need attempt number 10,001 to be the winner! **What am I doing wrong?**

I keep getting the error related to CORS, yet I've followed the guides to try to resolve it.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MES vs API");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

In react, I have this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:44387/api/Users/GetTest').then(function (response) {
      this.state.user = response.text();
});
```

Comment: I've managed to get the API call on client to remain stuck with a (pending) status. So there's.........that...

Comment: Please open the dev console in your react app and check the HTTP call under the "Network" tab of the console.
On the specific call is the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header present in the response headers ?

Comment: It was until I messed around in the Startup.cs - resulting in the code I posted. Now it stays at pending then eventually fails with a CONNECTION_RESET error in F12. It takes a few minutes for that to happen.

Comment: `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` move it over

Comment: move it over? to where?

Comment: not sure what you mean @MuhammetCaylak

Comment: this `app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin")` , `app.UseSwagger()` move over

Answer (score 0):

You are making http requests but you have HttpsRedirection enabled.

If you are developing without https you should move the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` call into a code block that will only be run in production. e.g.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else // Production
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MES vs API");
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(); // Use default policy as defined in example code
    //...
```

Also you are adding a default CORS policy but when you call `UseCors()` you are using a named policy (AllowAnyOrigin).

Either define a named policy "AllowAnyOrigin" or simply call `app.UseCors();` to use the default policy.

[Documentation on CORS in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors)

Comment: Does this change that it can work in both http and https mode?

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak In development both http and https (if certificate installed). In production it will only use https

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use it this way?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
       c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MES vs API");
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for the dependency injection container when setting the CORS policy

```
            //CORS CONFIGURATION
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

then applying the CORS policy

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            //ALLOW CORS
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```